# JMeter execute parallel using ForEach Controller

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute request per id so I use ForEach Controller

I'm getting results (list of ids) from SQL in JDBC Request and save in variable name id

I send request inside ForEach Controller with input variable id

The issue is that the requests are sent synchronically, how can I execute requests in parallel in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a new [Bug 65420](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65420) - ForEach Controller add ability to execute in parallel

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options:

1. Convert your variables into properties using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and execute them in parallel in another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) using:

   - the number of threads equal to the number of matches (rows)
   - [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the value(s) from JMeter Properties set by the previous Thread Group
   - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) if you need to run the requests at the same time
2. If your "requests" are [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) ones you can also consider using [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler)

Comment: Thank you for responding, but1. How will I go over properties in new thread group? if it's ForEach Controller it still be synchronically 2.requests are POST

Comment: Then the easiest is just to write the IDs into a temporary CSV file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) in 1st thread group and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in 2nd Thread Group to read the values.

Comment: thank you, but I need a realtime solution to execute immediately and with around million users propose solution will have overhead. I guess I need JMeter enhancement